# postgres read query resample time series data for hourly averages

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, timescaledb

I am new to SQL trying to learn how to do read queries on time series data. Can someone give me a tip on how to resample interval time series data to hourly averages on the postgres read query?

My table is named `building_data` where there are a few columns named `time, metric, value, kv_tags, m_tags`

`time` is my date/time stamp column where I am trying to see if I can resample the data in the `value` column into hourly averages. The `WHERE` in the query below is to filter out for a specific device that I am interested in looking at the data. I apologize if that doesn't make sense.

For a first timer this sql query appears to work but its not incorporating some process to resample the data in hourly averages, any tips greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
  "time" AS "time",
  metric AS metric,
  value,
  kv_tags,
  m_tags
FROM building_data
WHERE kv_tags->'equip_name' = '["35201"]' AND 
  m_tags IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY time desc limit 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use extract function:

```
select 
  extract (hour from "time") "hour"
  , "time"::date "day"
   , Avg(value)
from building_data
WHERE kv_tags->'equip_name' = '["35201"]' 
AND m_tags IS NOT NULL
group by 
     "time"::date
     ,extract (hour from "time")
ORDER BY 
   "time"::date desc
   , extract (hour from "time") desc
limit 1000
```

Comment: I get an errror: `': syntax error at or near ""day""
LINE 13:    "time"::date "day"  desc` any ideas?

Comment: @HenryHub opps , extra stuff in order by , see updated asnwer